# Identity Server Windows and Username Password

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

I have identity server 3 setup and working with Windows Authentication, I have the Identity Server instance and the Windows Auth in 2 separate projects, I store custom claims in the database so I add these claims to the token in order to not have to make Web Api use windows and have to check user claims on every request since I have a separate Javascript client that uses the service.  Great all works.

How do I add other authencation options to the identity server instance other type of clients? For Windows users in the domain I want to use Windows Auth and for users outside the domain I want to be able to show the login with username password but I don't want the windows users inside the domain to see the Identity Server page with the windows button.

I'm a little confused on how to setup this line:

```
factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(typeof(ExternalRegistrationUserService));

            var options = new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SigningCertificate = Certificate.Load(),
                Factory = factory,
                AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
                {
                    EnableLocalLogin = false,
                    IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders,

                }
            };
```

Do I need to seutp multiple Identity Servers or can one Instance Support Muliple AuthenticationOptions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple identity servers for that. Are you using identityserver 3 or 4? IdentityServer4 has a page in the documentation explaining how to do it with WebListener or Kestrel: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/windows.html

Comment: Identity server 3

Comment: I don't see anywhere how to set multiple Authentication options??